# Why when ploting the ICLabel in EEGLAB some of the IC topographs look exaclty the same?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, speech, eeg, ica

I am attaching an image with the output of ICLabel. So you can see that IC5 and IC6 are the same. What does this mean?  [image]

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They aren't identical, as least as different as 3&4, can you clarify what you are asking about and provide some background information?